# security updates reported but not actually available (recommended==installed)

Tags: updating, security

I installed Drupal 9.3.6.

At `/admin/reports/status`, I see the error:

> There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes

and at `/admin/modules/update`, two modules are listed: [PHP 8.x-1.1](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) and [Remote Stream Wrapper 8.x-1.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper).

However, for both these modules the recommended version is the already-installed version.

- How do I see more details about the reason for the errors?
- Alternatively, can I make Drupal ignore these two modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes* isn't the more appropriate message that is correct in every case. It assumes that, once a release has been marked as insecure, a new release is created, but that doesn't always happen, for example because the project owner or one of the maintainers failed to fix the security issue.

In the specific case:

- [All the releases for the *PHP* module has been marked insecure](https://www.drupal.org/project/php/releases); this means you cannot install a release that isn't marked insecure
- [The 8.x-1.5 release for the *Remote Stream Wrapper* module has been marked insecure](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper/releases/8.x-1.5); [there aren't more recent releases](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper/releases) and [the project has been marked unsupported](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper)

Implementing [`hook_update_status_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_status_alter/9.0.x) in a module, you can set those modules as ignored.

```php
use Drupal\update\UpdateFetcherInterface;

function mymodule_update_status_alter(&$projects) {
  if (isset($projects['php'])) {
    $projects['php']['status'] = UpdateFetcherInterface::UNKNOWN;
    $projects['php']['reason'] = t('MyModule prevents Drupal from receiving information about module updates .');
  }
  if (isset($projects['remote_stream_wrapper'])) {
    $projects['remote_stream_wrapper']['status'] = UpdateFetcherInterface::UNKNOWN;
    $projects['php']['reason'] = t('MyModule prevents Drupal from receiving information about module updates .');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This code seems to prevent the permanent error being shown while not hiding that the modules are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Drupal messages regarding module updates can be outdated and can be fixed by manual check for updates from the /admin/reports/updates page: [image]

Also, some error messages can be shown because of the "Remote Stream Wrapper" module's status:
[image]

To avoid receiving such messages you can:

1. Uninstall the Update MAnager module.
2. Try to use the [hook_update_projects_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_projects_alter/9.0.x)